# The topology on $X / G$ where $G$ acts on $X$

Tags: general-topology, group-actions, quotient-spaces

The elements are orbits, but how do we find the neighbourhoods?

In particular, let $G= ( \mathbb R^+ , \cdot )$ and $X=[0, \infty )$.

Let $G$ act on $X$ via the usual multiplication.

Then $X/G = {\bigg \{ } \{0 \} \ , \ (0, \infty )  {\bigg \} }$ has two elements.

- I guess the topology on $X/G$ is not discrete. What is it?
- Can I consider $G$ only as a group to define a topology on $X/G$? Or
  does $G$ have to be a topological group?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be helpful to consider the quotient topology.  Let $\pi: X \to X/G$ be the projection mapping.  Then $U \subseteq X/G$ is open if and only if $\pi^{-1}(U) \subseteq X$ is open.  Using this idea we then have only a few subsets to check.  Clearly $\pi^{-1}(\emptyset) = \emptyset$ and $\pi^{-1}(X/G) = X$.  We then have that $\pi^{-1}(\{\{0\}\}) = \{0\}$ which is not open in $[0,\infty)$.  We do however have that $\pi^{-1}(\{(0,\infty)\}) = (0,\infty)$ which is open in $[0,\infty)$ so this subset is open.  Therefore the topology on $X/G$ is given by

$$
\mathcal{T} \;\; =\;\; \Big\{\emptyset, X/G, \{(0,\infty)\}    \Big\}.
$$

Comment: Thanks. Why did you call the map "projection" ? And as I understand from your answer, the group $G$ doesn't have to be a topological group in order to define the topology on $X/G$, is that right?

Comment: @ThePortakal By "projection" I mean the map that takes each element of $X$ to its orbit in $X/G$.  So in your example if $x \neq 0$ then $\pi(x) = (0,\infty)$, and $\pi(0) = \{0\}$.  And no, $G$ doesn't need to be a topological group in order for it to act on a topological space.  However, some of the more important/exciting theorems do require a topology on $G$.  Even if $G$ is finite or discrete it is possible to define the discrete topology on $G$, but in this case it is not needed.

Comment: @ThePortakal This is the Sierpinski Space: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space